# TYPO3 link child elements in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I want that submenu elements of level 2 do not load a new page.

They should link to an anchor.

Is that possible and when how?

My current typoscript for level two looks like this:

```
 2 < .1
        2 {
            // Adjust several classes for sublevels
            wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu  multi-level">|</ul>
            IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown-submenu">|</li>
            ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown-submenu active">|</li>
            // Remove caret element (correct arrow is set with ::after pseudo element)
            IFSUB.linkWrap >
            ACTIFSUB.linkWrap >

            CURIFSUB < .ACTIFSUB

            SPC = 1
            SPC {
                wrapItemAndSub.cObject = COA
                wrapItemAndSub.cObject {
                    // no divider, if first menu item on this level:
                    10 = TEXT
                    10.value = <li class="dropdown-header">|</li>
                    10.if.value.data = register:count_MENUOBJ
                    10.if.equals = 1

                    // otherwise:
                    20 = TEXT
                    20.value = <li class="divider"></li><li class="dropdown-header">|</li>
                    20.if.value.data = register:count_MENUOBJ
                    20.if.equals = 1
                    20.if.negate = 1
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: TMENU items have the `doNotLinkIt` property. Is it useful for you?

Comment: please specify your request: what do you have? (your current output) / what do you want to reach? (your desired output) / reduce your code/example to the minimum (a big part of your 'code' handles spacers (in a complicated way: why do you avoid optionsplits?) without any links)

Comment: I simplified the spacer configuration. We still need to know to which anchor the second level should link. If you for example want to link all content elements (which have anchors/ids) from the pages on the first level, you could use [sectionIndex](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/MenuObjects/Sectionindex/).